# Secret way to trigger Thesaurus on Mac OS X?

Tags: keyboard, macos

Not really sure how to ask since I have no idea what just happened, but I'll try my best :-)

I just typed "I" into a textfield here on Yosemite and then tried to click on an icon in the Mac OS status bar (with the option key and some other key pressed AFAIK), but I missed and the next thing I saw was a dropdown that contained the entries "He", "She", "It", "You", "We", ...I am unable to reproduce and would like to know what this was and how to  make it happen again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you pressed the <kbd>esc</kbd> key. Yosemite has a similar feature to iOS 8's QuickType keyboard that "intelligently predicts" what you are trying to type. It looks like this:

[image: Predictive text menu on OS X Yosemite]

Is this what appeared?

Comment: That is it! Is that new in Yosemite?

Comment: It is. It wasn't really advertised, which is why many people don't know about it.

Comment: But it's not working everywhere (just tried in a new email). Found this for reference: http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/09/04/new-quicktype-like-feature-found-in-os-x-yosemite/

Comment: That's true. I've found it only works in certain text areas. As an OS X developer, I've managed to get it working in NSTextViews, but not all text areas. I'm not entirely sure on what determines whether or not it is available in a given place.

Answer (score 2):

What I think you saw is the writing suggestions, accessible by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may have seen Spotlight. It has a built in Dictionary, Thesaurus, and Calculator. It's a little magnifying glass in the menu bar, towards the top and right of the screen.

What you probably hit was <kbd>**⌥Option**</kbd>+<kbd>**⌘Command**</kbd>+<kbd>**⇧Shift**</kbd>.